# How to make an if statement point free

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I have the following if statement:

```
var formatCity = 
    obj => R.both(has('city'), has('state'))(obj) ? appendCommaToCity(obj) : obj
```

I would like to make this code point free, but can not figure out a way around the if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's quite simple actually using the [`ifElse` function](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ifElse) - or its specialisation, [`when`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#when):

```
const formatCity = R.when(R.both(has('city'), has('state')), appendCommaToCity);
```